# Access key from mapValues or flatMapValues?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark 1.3, is there a way to access the key from `mapValues`?

Specifically, if I have

```
val y = x.groupBy(someKey)
val z = y.mapValues(someFun)
```

can `someFun` know which key of y it is currently operating on?

Or do I have to do

```
val y = x.map(r => (someKey(r), r)).groupBy(_._1)
val z = y.mapValues{ case (k, r) => someFun(r, k) }
```

Note: the reason I want to use `mapValues` rather than `map` is to preserve the partitioning.

Comment: @ayanguha `x` is an RDD

Comment: So, why can't you use map instead of mapValues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the key with `mapValues`. But you can preserve the partitioning with the `mapPartitions`.

```
val pairs: Rdd[(Int, Int)] = ???
pairs.mapPartitions({ it =>
  it.map { case (k, v) =>
    // your code
  }
}, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

Be careful to actually preserve the partitioning, the compiler will not be able to check it.

Answer (score 10):

In this case you can use `mapPartitions` with the `preservesPartitioning` attribute.

```
x.mapPartitions((it => it.map { case (k,rr) => (k, someFun(rr, k)) }), preservesPartitioning = true)
```

You just have to make sure you are not changing the partitioning, i.e. don't change the key.

Comment: Is this as officiant as mapValues?

Comment: They both boil down to the same thing, a MapPartitionRDD with preservesPartitioning set to true, so the performance should be the same as long as you actually preserve the partitioning

Answer (score 0):

You can apply zipWithIndex().map(lambda x : (x[1], x[0])).mapValues() after doing groupByKey(). It will give you the (key, value) pair in mapValues function.